# How to do a password less signin in flutter with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am unable to know how to do [passwordless signin](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/implementing-passwordless-email-authentication-with-amazon-cognito/) [with OTP](https://techinscribed.com/passwordless-phone-number-authentication-using-aws-amplify-cognito/) using cognito in flutter.
I just need assistance with the flutter code for sending the OTP and answering the auth challenger with any working cognito/amplify package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to do with this package: [amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2](https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2)

```
//Create a cognito user
CognitoUser cognitoUser1;

//Send OTP
 cognitoUser1 = CognitoUser(phoneNumber.text, widget.userPool);
  try {
    CognitoUserSession cognitoUserSession =
        await cognitoUser1.initiateAuth(
      AuthenticationDetails(
        authParameters: [
          AttributeArg(
            name: 'phone_number',
            value: phoneNumber.text,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  } catch (cognitoUserCustomChallengeException) {}
  

//Authenticate the user
CognitoUserSession cognitoUserSession = await cognitoUser1.sendCustomChallengeAnswer(otp.text);

print("jwtToken " + cognitoUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken);
print("refreshToken " + cognitoUserSession.refreshToken.token);
```

Comment: Can you show more of the code pls or a bit more explanation because I'm stuck on the same issue and don't know how to approach it